BV function $f$ is $\|Df\|$-measurable
Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a $L^1$-function of bounded variation where the total variation measure $\|Df\|(\mathbb R)$ is bounded, i.e. $f\in BV(\mathbb R)$.
Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, we have that $f$ is measurable with respect to $1$-Lebesgue measure $\mathcal L^1$ on $\mathbb R$. So, my question is that "Is $f$ is measurable with respect to measure $\|Df\|$? or there is a  representative of $f$ is $\|Df\|$-measurable?" For instance, the representative $\bar f:=(f^\vee+f^\wedge)/2$? where $f^\vee, f^\wedge$ are the upper and lower approximate of $f$.
Let $A$ be a measurable on $\mathbb R$. Since $f$ is $\mathcal L^1$-measurable, then there is a null set $N$, $\mathcal L^1(N)=0$, so that $N\cup f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable. Hence, if $\mathcal L^1(N)=0$ implies $\|Df\|(N)=0$ then f is also $\|Df\|$-measurable. However, the part "if" may fail, for instance the jump set $N$. So, I would like to know when $f$ is $\|Df\|$-measurable.
Thanks!
